# How to fit an ARIMA (p,d,q) model with drift term in R

Tags: r, statistics

Actually i have got a tentative model using auto.arima which gives me an ARIMA(0,1,1) model with a drift. So to fit my model i need to use the arima function in R, but since i have got a drift term, what will be the exact function in R to fit such a model?

Answer (score 1):

`auto.arima()` returns the model for you. You don't have to fit it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify in

> Arima(data, c(0,1,1), include.drift=TRUE)

You can only include a drift when d+D < 1